# How to add new field to JHI_USER in JHipster

Tags: java, mysql, jhipster

I have a JHipster App setup. I just need to add a column gender to the User Table and the other changes associated with it. Is there any way to make JHipster do this? trying to add an entity with the name JHI_USER ends up trying to create it and failing.

Answer (score 0):

You must do it by hands, add your column in `domain/User` and don`t forget update your liquibase settings.

Answer (score 0):

Less intrusive: you add another entity that would contain all the additional fields you need and add a one-to-one relationship with user.

This way you can re-generate your app with more recent version and keep your changes.

Comment: I'm gonna try this. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, could you tell us what you did to correct your problem ?